# How to check 3 initial digit on the User ID with PHP?

Tags: php

First of all, I'm sorry if my english is bad. I wanna ask how to check 3 initial digit on the User ID? for example, for my department in university, student number 06411111 is for Informatics Engineering department, that's because the 3 initial digit ( 064 ) is code for informatics engineering department. And I want to make validation form where user id without 064 in the beginning, they are not Informatics Engineering Student. So this is my code :

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$check_digit = strlen($userid);
$check_digit2 = strlen($password);

if($check_digit == 8 || $check_digit == 12){
    if (!eregi("[0-9]", $userid)){
        echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('User id contain only numeric characters.');</script>";} else {
            if($check_digit2 >= 7){
                $encrypt=md5($password);} else { echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('The length of the password must be >= 7.');</script>";}
                 } }else {
                            echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('The length of the user id must be 8 or 12 digits');</script>";
                 }
```

Thank you in advance for your help and once again I'm sorry if my english is bad (got a warning before because unclear question).

Comment: first of all stop using `md5` for storing passwords.

Comment: @Subhanker that's a provision for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($userid, '064') === 0)
  echo 'You are in ICT';
else
  echo 'You are not';
```

Comment: if I wanna to validate 2 codes for department, it should be `if(strpos($userid, '064') && ($userid, '065') === 0)`. Right or not? Thankyou.